# Convert realtime sensor data Byte to Float

Tags: android, bluetooth, spi

I am not much of a programmer and am trying to make a sensor interact with an app. The app is a simple app that receives SPI data over bluetooth from the sensor hub and displays it. The data from the sensor arrives in a byte[] array with 4 bytes. I am able to display the byte array as 8 hex characters on the android screen.

I am now trying to display human readable data on the screen. For this, I need to isolate 12 bits (bits 28 to 16) from the 4 byte stream and mask the rest of it. Then I need to convert these 12 bits to an integer and divide it by 16 to display the final sensor reading.

Any hints on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Which bits are in the first byte?

Comment: @stark: The first byte is in bits 23 to 16. LSB is in bit 16.

Comment: What language are you using?